# How to get read count of blogs in Blog module?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using blog module to implement blog section in my website, I am not getting the count of the each blog. What is the variable that stores read count of each blog. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core **Blog** module does not track read statistics for content; that's the purview of the **Statistics** module.

To enable read statistics:

1. Install the Statistics module.
2. Follow its configuration link (**/admin/config/system/statistics**).
3. Set the **Count content views** option to enable view counting.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. But in which variable that is stored. Because I am displaying blogs through template files. So which variable I need to print in template file so that I can see the read count.

Comment: You could utilize the `statistics_get()` function, but you'd be better off rendering node links which the module already adds the statistics count to.